# How to remove white padding/borders that tint::tintHtml added around cells in kable table?

Tags: r-markdown, kable, tint

I'd like to get rid of the white around each cells.  When I knit to html_document there is no such padding.

I'm guessing the tint.css file is responsible for this (https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/tintHtml/resources/tint.css)

````
---
title: tintHtml() add padding to kable "
output:  tint::tintHtml
---
  
  
  
```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)
```


```{r}
knitr::kable(
  mtcars[1:6, 1:6], 
  caption = 'how do I get rid of white padding ?'
) %>%  
  row_spec(0, background = "blue", color = "white") %>% 
  row_spec(1, background = "green", color = "white") 

```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one: You may "right-click an element on a web page and select [Inspect Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector)"

[image]

Step two: You will need to override the default [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) (Bootstrap CSS) property:

> The [border-spacing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp) property sets the distance between the borders of
> adjacent cells.
> Note: This property works only when **border-collapse** is
> **separate**.

```
<style>
table{
  border-spacing: unset;    # values: inherent, initial, unset or 0px
}
</style>
```

Output:

````
---
title: tintHtml() add padding to kable "
output: tint::tintHtml
---
  
```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)
```
<style>
table{
  border-spacing: unset;    # inherent, initial, unset, 0px
}
</style>

```{r}
knitr::kable(
  mtcars[1:6, 1:6], 
  caption = 'how do I get rid of white padding ?'
) %>%  
  row_spec(0, background = "blue", color = "white") %>% 
  row_spec(1, background = "green", color = "white") 
```
````

[image]